# Accordion Collapsible Does not work only in Heroku (CSP Issue)

Tags: jquery, express, bootstrap-4, content-security-policy, helmet.js

Iam facing a very strange issue. I implemented some nested collapsible and also simple collapsible that work excellent at localhost.But in Heroku still i cannot understand why collapsibles do not work. Any help is welcomed, without working collapsible my web app will appear chaotic :(

Pug Layout

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
    head
        title= title
        meta(charset='utf-8')
        meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
        script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js", integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj", crossorigin="anonymous")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css", integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z", crossorigin="anonymous")
        script(src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js", integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV", crossorigin="anonymous")
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    body
    div(class='container-fluid')
      div(class='row')
        div(class='col-sm-2')
          block sidebar
            ul(class='sidebar-nav')
              li
                a(href='/catalog') Home
              li
                a(href='/catalog/resources') All Resources

              li
                a(href='/catalog/bookings') My Bookings
        div(class='col-sm-10')
          block content
```

Collapsible PUG

```
extends layout
block content
  -var i=0;
  -var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
        #accordion.panel-group
        each doc in object
           flex-container(style='background-color:#c7e7fa; justify-content:space-around; position:relative;flex-direction:row;margin-left:20px;margin-right:auto; margin-top:20px; width:45%; ')
            .three(style='text-align:center;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; flex: 0 0 40%;')
              h4='' + doc._id.year + '  ' + months[doc._id.month - 1]
              -i++;
            #accordion.panel-group
             .panel-heading
               h4.panel-title
                 a.accordion-toggle(data-toggle='collapse', href='#collapses' + i)
                   h6 See Total Cost
             .panel-collapse.collapse.in(id="collapses" + i)
                .three(style='width:100%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; flex: 0 0 25%;')
                  h5= 'Total Montly Cost:  ' + doc.total_cost_month.toFixed(2)
                                .panel-heading
                                  h4.panel-title
                                    a.accordion-toggle(data-toggle='collapse', href='#collapse'+i)
                                      hr
                                      h6 See All Booking details
                                .panel-collapse.collapse.in(id="collapse"+i)
                                  each booking in doc.bookings_month
                                    flex-container(style='background-color:#a6f1a6; width:100%;')
                                                three.flex-container
                                                    | #[strong Start:] #{moment(booking.date_started).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')}
                                                three.flex-container
                                                    | #[strong  Finish:] #{moment(booking.date_finished).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')}
                                                three.flex-container
                                                    | #[strong  Cost:]  #{booking.total_cost.toFixed(2)}
                                                li
        else
            h1 No booking history found
            h3= 'Start booking now' + "  "
             a(href='/catalog/resources')
              | here:
```

Comment: is there any link that can be open?

Comment: Open link? Do you mean in terms of code syntax? i think that is ok, cause it works at localhost. I dont know, but from what i saw in similar issues in stackoverflow, according some suggestions, may i change the order of links? e.g first jquery then bootstrap? may the versions of bootstrap/jquery are incompatible? By the way the link for jquery/bootstrap are the same as MDN local-library tutorial
https://github.com/mdn/express-locallibrary-tutorial/blob/master/views/layout.pug

Comment: Any errors in dev tools console?

Comment: @charlietfl 
I will check dev tools, even if iam newbie and iam not familiar with detecting in such a way. So this is my exact page i want to fix https://nameless-escarpment-67481.herokuapp.com/catalog/billing/606f7badc297a70015be79d7

Comment: Look at the generated source. The body is closed before the content. Also need `https:` added to the jQuery script src. That file is being blocked loading

Comment: I found these messages  https://i.ibb.co/kDzTS8L/imag.png
I dont know why this caused. I will check now what you suggest me and i 'll come back

Comment: @charlietfl. I added the https, it was mistake during copy paste :). What about body that closes before content i checked MDN original layout and i think they are both the same.So from my quick overview i think  that i found what causes the problem. The problem is that the heroku deployed app refuses some bootstrap/jquery packages, while my localhost app does not print logs to dev tools console. So we have now to find how to fix this refused issues
Refused to load the script '

Comment: So after some research, i think that the problem is server side. Iam using Node Js Express framework with Helmet Js, so i will have look there how to customize my Content Sec Policies. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's solved . The problem sources from the server-side. Especially from helmetjs, app.use(helmet()). So helmet by default blocks every content like script stylesheets and multimedia links that are loading in the pug views, in order to prevent XSS attacks. So what we have to do, is to tell helmet that we want to whitelist some link references, which could be a stylesheet link,  a script link and image link etc. We do that by including in our code (app.js) this code fragment.

```
app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy:{
    directives:{
      "default-src":["'self'"],
      "script-src":["https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js","'sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj'","https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js","'sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV'"],
      "style-src": ["'self'","https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css","'unsafe-inline'"],
      "object-src":["'none'"],


    },
  }
}
));
```

So helmet is a module that we have already imported in our app. This module has some properties. In our issue we focus on the property contentSecurityPolicy, cause we need to solve a CSP problem. To put some exceptions we add them inside `directives` property.These exceptions are key-value pairs, where key is the type of the content that will be loaded in our web app and the value is the actual link  that carries the content. So now we will adress the solution, be carefull at the order of the properties because that is very important. `"default-src":["'self'"]` is the by default property and we tell web app  to load content only from its domain `'self'`.
Next comes the `"script-src"`, this is our jquery script with the hash taken from our layoyt above and also the script that uses our bootstrap stylesheet, and this has also its hash. Then it is `"style-src"` which is the actual bootstrap template, we add `'self'` (iam not pretty sure if self is not optional) and then we use `"'unsafe-inline'"` which means that our app loads the hash that exist in each particular pug template. Finally `"object-src"` is a property we should assign as `"'none'"`.
So thats it be carefull about the order of the commands